# Installing 32-bit Software Outside %windir%\Program Files (x86) on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32-bit app that I need to install and test on a Windows 2008 R2 server. This app has some dependencies on 3rd party 32-bit software (Oracle 10g client and TCL runtime -- a large portion of the app is TCL scripts). This app also creates Windows services to run.

The current version of the product requires that its binaries (`.exe`s and `.dll`s) and scripts be installed to `D:\App`. This path is hard-coded in the scripts and config files. It also requires that the TCL runtime be installed to `D:\TCL`.

I'm concerned that if I try to install 32-bit binaries outside of `%windir%\Program Files (x86)`, then weird things will happen; are my concerns warranted? Are there any side effects or issues with running 32-bit apps outside of `%windir%\Program Files (x86)` on Windows 2008 R2? Does our app have to do anything special with the binaries if they're running outside the `%windir%\Program Files (x86)` folder?

Comment: Please don't crosspost the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: If you're the developer of this app, please fix it so it works correctly -- living under %PROGRAMFILES%. It is often a source of complication/trouble, for sysadmins, when application developers choose to ignore a platform's standards.

Comment: @jscott; I am not a developer, but work for the company that develops this app. If you could site specific examples of how not installing to %PROGRAMFILES% causes problems, I can use that in my argument that we need to fix the app to really support 64-bit Windows environments. Right now it looks like our app works, so there's little incentive to fix it.

Comment: From a quick search, here are two example questions from the SF community. I realize they do not address your *exact* situation, but you should be able to gauge the sorts of issues breaking standards/traditions can cause for sysadmins. [EXEs from a share](http://serverfault.com/questions/169534/why-do-some-admins-dislike-exes-being-executed-from-a-server-share) and [EXEs from %APPDATA%](http://serverfault.com/questions/178565/do-admins-mind-exes-being-copied-installed-to-the-users-application-data-folder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work fine.  Windows will detect it's a 32-bit EXE, wrap it up in Wow64, and away you go.

I rarely use "Program Files" or its 32-bit equivalent, as I have a pet hate about directories names with spaces in.  I've experienced no problems at all.